# SQL , временные таблицы

Tags: sql, temporary-table

Мне нужно написать скрипт, с использованием временной таблицы, где будут следующие поля : NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME. Из результата временной таблицы удалить всех клиентов, возраст которых менее 15 лет. В итоге отобразить OS телефона и количество людей у которых эта OS.

как создать временную таблицу? мне через час нужно будет отправить руководителю решение данного вопроса, а я в создании таблиц не в зуб ногой

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as [Number of people with OS],
    OS_NAME 
    FROM 
    #temptable
    where 
    age >= 15
    GROUP BY
    OS_NAME
```

Comment: *как создать временную таблицу?* Указывайте конкретную СУБД - у каждой это делается по-своему.

Comment: да, как создать временную таблицу с указаными полями, конкретную субд руководитель мне не давал, я так понял что в любой СУБД подойдет ответ.

Comment: *конкретную субд руководитель мне не давал* Ну так пойди и спроси.

Comment: Нет никакой возможности в данный момент связатся с руководителем, для создания временных таблиц мои колеги используют MySQL. Полагаю что в данной СУБД нужно создать временную таблицу....

Comment: В MySQL временная таблица создаётся запросом `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

Comment: CREATE TABLE #temptable
 SELECT * FROM #temptable
есть такое дело.
А как внести в таблицу указаные поля: NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME.

Comment: Следует указать полную спецификацию для каждого поля.

Comment: Ты только потом сообщи, как принял ответ руководитель

Comment: там такая противная тетка, ужас... судя по всему мне конец (

Comment: Ты держись там. Мы за тебя держим кулачки! Почитай ещё что-нибудь на SO и удиви её знаниями!

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xxx ( NAME text NOT NULL, SURNAME text NOT NULL, AGE text NOT NULL, OS_NAME text NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8